# Randomizing XML files

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I am making a multiple choice quiz in Action Script 3 and I want to store my questions and answers in a XML file. When the quiz is ran I want to pull 20 questions from the XML file and randomize them. Any ideas on how I could put all the questions and answers from the XML file into an array and randomize that array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML question wasn't very specific, so I'll just assume you don't know where to start. [This](http://www.blog.mpcreation.pl/actionscript-30-basics-part-3-loading-xml-data/) should get you going on loading and parsing XML.

Once you have an array of questions, you can pull twenty random ones using a simple loop and array.splice to move them into a new array:

```
var questions:Array = new Array();
while(questions.length < 20) {
    questions.push(xmlQuestions.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * xmlQuestions.length), 1));
}
```

This will choose a random index between 0 and n (where n is the length of the array containing all questions) and remove that element, then push it into the new array.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the xml node of the each question and its answer, into an internal class. This will make it easier for you to manage the data.

This will output an array of objects of your class type.
Then you shuffle the array thusly

```
myArray.sort( function( obj0:*,obj1:* ):Boolean{ return Math.random() < 0.5; } );
```

Then you just loop the array one by one. Since your data is in the object itself, the answer and other related things travel with the object in the sort area. Thus you don't have to permute the associated answers, too.

Note: the sort function does not care what object type it is, so I used universal type for the parameters.

Comment: user1884296 does this answer satisfy your issue?